# Can't change permissions after deleting and re-creating bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I've ran into some trouble with GCS buckets that were deleted and then re-created (with the same names). If that is relevant, they are 'domain buckets' for hosting static content. After creating the buckets anew, I can no longer change any permission on those buckets. I get some unhelpful error message but no chance to change the permissions. Is there some kind of period to elapse before this problem goes away? In case of one bucket it's been way more than 24 hours and still no change.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I posted this at the cusp of the time limit. Took more than 24 hours for one bucket, less than 12 for others. Problem solved itself.